# Having issues about architectural design regarding AS3, FB, and Django

Tags: android, django, facebook, actionscript-3

I am developing an application using ActionScript3 / Flex for Android.

The fact is that I am a newbie at ActionScript 3 with Facebook, and I found this library:

[Facebook Actionscript API](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/).

I have this class:

```
package com.mirrorlings.facebook {

    import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;

    public class WebAppDriver extends AppDriver {

        private var init_options:Object = {};

        public function WebAppDriver(
            app_id:String,
            app_perms:Array = [],
            user_logged_in:Function = null,
            user_not_logged_in:Function = null,
            user_clear:Function = null,
            app_init_options:Object = null,
            app_token:String = null
        ) {
            super(app_id, "", app_perms, user_logged_in, user_not_logged_in, user_clear, app_token);
            this.init_options = app_init_options;
        }

        override public function init():void {

            Facebook.init(this.app_id, function(result:Object, fail:Object):void {
                if (result) {
                    this.user_logged_in();
                } else {
                    this.user_not_logged_in();
                }
            }, this.init_options, this.app_token);

        }

        override public function login():void {

            var context:WebAppDriver = this;
            Facebook.login(function(response:Object, fail:Object):void {
                if (response) {
                    context.user_logged_in();
                }
            }, {scope: this.app_perms.join(",")});

        }

        override public function logout():void {

            var context:WebAppDriver = this;
            Facebook.logout(function(success:Boolean):void {
                context.user_clear();
                context.user_not_logged_in();
            });

        }

    }

}
```

Intention of the class:

1. Initializing the API (showing content depending on if the user was logged in).
2. Log in a user.
3. Log out a user - clean data, and show the not-logged-in content.

My **question #1** is: Will it generate a standard facebook cookie?

This means: If I develop the endpoint (did not develop it yet) with a normal facebook API in Python/Django/[Fandjango](http://fandjango.readthedocs.org/)...

```
from fandjango.decorators import facebook_authorization_required

@facebook_authorization_required
def view(request):
    #return a response here
```

...which is a normal facebook application entry point: will a request like this

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
//... more settings
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://my.site/path/to/such/view"));
```

include the facebook cookie?

The fact is that I did not develop the backend, but also I don't know if I'm in the right way. My final intention is to create a facebook game for android/AS3 which connects to my site (such connections must be fb-authorized), and one of those urls is the entry to a Websocket connection point (will be a websocket-implemented game for facebook users).

Any guidelines or architectural tips you could give me? (again: needed components are Facebook, ActionScript3 compiled for Android, with a backend in Django/Fandjango and Websockets for the connection).

Comment: Can't you use regular form submissions/xml for communicating with the backend (REST) instead of sockets?  Keep the clientside and backend separate?

Comment: Will be a real-time game, so I will need a real-time communication (and not just a long-polling). I don't expect to have many ports available, but can only expect to install an nginx - 3 reasons to go for websockets